# Button implements the wrong code when press 'enter' button

Tags: php, html, post, forms

I am writing code that is meant to log in users.

The login and search worked before but, ever since I combined the two the login form doesn't implement it's own code and instead, it runs the search code

EDIT: I found out why this happens, it's because I have been pressing enter instead of selecting login. So now I want to know, how do I press enter and implement the login code.

Below is the headerPublic.php which contains the search code

```
<?php
//---------------------BEGIN SEARCH FROM THE SEARCH BAR IN PUBLIC HEADER----------------------------------


    if(isset($_POST["search_button"]))
        {                   

             //PHP SEARCH CODE

        }


//---------------------END SEARCH FROM THE SEARCH BAR IN PUBLIC HEADER----------------------------------
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>VCR Exchange</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <nav>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>


<!------------------------------------SEARCH BAR---------------------------------------------->
                    <li>    
                    <form role="search" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="search" name="search">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" value = "search" name="search_button">Search</button>

                </li>
<!------------------------------------SEARCH BAR---------------------------------------------->

                    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
```

And this is the login.php.

```
<?php require('connect.php'); ?>
<?php require('headerPublic.php'); ?>
<?php require('session.php'); ?>

         <form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

            <label for="inputEmail" >Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">

            <label for="inputPassword" >Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

            <button name="login" type="submit">Login</button>

         </form>

    </body>
</html>


<?php

    // IF LOGIN BUTTON IS CLICKED:
    if (isset($_POST['login']))
    {

        //LOG IN CODE

    }

?>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you never close the search form in your html.

Comment: You are also vulnerable to SQL injections, and will get errors from searches with single quotes.

Comment: Just added the closing </form> tag and it works

Comment: Great. I don't remember why I commented about SQLi. There's no SQL in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search form was missing a closing form tag

```
 <!------------------------------------SEARCH BAR---------------------------------------------->
                        <li>    
                        <form role="search" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="search" name="search">
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" value = "search" name="search_button">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
    <!------------------------------------SEARCH BAR---------------------------------------------->
```